# How to evaluate the effect of each group in dummy D to endogenous variable X in 2SLS regression?

Tags: regression, interaction, econometrics, regression-coefficients, 2sls

I have a question in terms of evaluating the effect of a dummy $D$ to endogenous variable $X$ in two-stage least squares (2SLS) regression.

Suppose I have dependent variable $Y$, endogenous variable $X$, exogenous variable $W$ and $D$ ($D$ is categorical which should be converted to a dummy), $Z$ is an instrument. I am performing 2SLS regression now, and I want to see the difference of coefficient $X$ in each category of $D$. How should I do that? I have three thoughts, but not sure which one is correct:

1. Run 2SLS regression for each category of $D$ separately, and get the coefficient of $X$.
2. Add the interaction term of $D$ and $X$.
3. See the first stage result and use the coefficient of each category of $D$.